# Let $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ be closed, and $p\in A^c$. Let $S=\{ d(p,y) \mid y \in A \}$. Show that $\inf S \in S$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Let $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ be closed, and $p\in A^c$. Let $S=\{ d(p,y) \mid y \in A \}$. Show that $\inf S \in S$.

I tried to show $S$ is closed, but I think I came up with an counter example by setting $A=R$. Does anyone have an idea on how to approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take any $y_0\in A$ (assuming $A\ne\emptyset$) and define
$$
A_0=\{y\in A\,\mid\, d(p,y)\le d(p,y_0)\},\quad S_0=\{d(p,y)\,\mid\,y\in A_0\}.
$$
Then we have $A_0$ is compact, $d$ is continuous, so $\inf S_0\in S_0$. Moreover, by the construction $\inf S=\inf S_0$ and $S_0\subset S$, therefore, $\inf S\in S$.